# Creating depth of field from Beauty+Depth passes (rendered in another software)

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, depth-of-field

Creating DoF in the compositor is very easy if you have the scene rendered in Blender and the camera depth set right. But what if you rendered a beauty (raw render) and depth pass in another program?

[image: Beauty Pass]

[image: Depth Pass]

This was rendered in Maya, the white is at the front and the black at the back. There is no "focal distance" value on the Defocus node, so I don't know how to tell it what distance is supposed to be in focus.

I also tried using a regular blur node with "Variable Size" on (Gaussian Type) after putting the depth through a color ramp to remap the values, but this causes areas in focus to have the out-of-focus background blur "bleed" into them:

[image: Remapped depth]

[image: Blur Bleed]

(The whole worm should be in focus, no blurred edges)

So how should I create depth of field using these two passes alone and no access to the scene itself (since it's in another software)?

Comment: That's an awesome scene.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Defocus node works in conjunction with the settings for the active camera.

You can use this node setup:

[image]

You have to check "Use Z-Buffer" so your depth image is used. If you omit the Add node all parts of the image where the depth image is black are sharp independent of your focal settings. I don't know why, maybe that's a bug.

You also have to set the "Distance" to `1.0` with your active camera selected under Properties > Camera Data > Depth of Field.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have to set the camera distance to 1.0? Why not 2.0 or 10?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. But I guess that white in the depth image corresponds to 1.0 and black to 0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is how I'll setup the compositor to do that :

- Defocus node : be sure to check `use Z-buffer`.
- Set Alpha on the "depth pass image" (the B/W one), with a `less than` math converter before. This will allow us to override the blurred worm (and other things which are on the same plane) by a focused one. The "Full focused" filed can be controlled by the `Less Than` value.
- Alpha over : be sure to check `Convert Premult`.

[image: defocus node setup]

Note that I only have a 960x540 image to test, so it's a bit pixelated here, but it should work as you expect in full HD. (I hope)

Cheers