# How to blur only the foreground?

Tags: blur, depth-of-field

like in photography I would like to have a blurry foreground and the rest of my scene focused to infinity (including the world background), I was unable to get this effect using the Depth of Field feature. (using Blender v. 2.76)

Comment: Any particular reason you are using 2.76? Honestly I don't even remember what features were in it.

Comment: Also this should answer your question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3715/creating-depth-of-field-from-beautydepth-passes-rendered-in-another-software?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your answer cgslav, I use 2.76 because I'm stuck with Windows XP, living thus in prehistoric times... will check your link  ;)